# split a log file containing multiple subfiles into the subfiles

Tags: powershell

On a Windows system, I have a log file that consists of several XML files concatenated together.

Each embedded XML file starts with: 
`<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>`

I'd like to write out each individual embedded XML file into its own separate file.

I have been playing with powershell but can't quite pull it together

Sample file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>                                                                                 
<INSTANCES>                                                                                                            
  <INSTANCE>                                                                                                           
    <HOST_NAME>sstest</HOST_NAME>                                                                               
    <INSTANCE_NAME>SSTEST1</INSTANCE_NAME>                                                                              
    <DATABASE_NAME>SSTEST</DATABASE_NAME>                                                                               
    <OPEN_MODE>READ WRITE</OPEN_MODE>                                                                                  
    <DATABASE_ROLE>PRIMARY</DATABASE_ROLE>                                                                             
    <CREATED>2016-01-18</CREATED>                                                                                      
    <DBID>192837465</DBID>                                                                                            
  </INSTANCE>                                                                                                          
</INSTANCES>                                                                                                           
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>                                                                                 
<PARAMS>                                                                                                               
  <PARAM>                                                                                                              
    <NAME>enable_logging</NAME>                                                                                    
    <VALUE>FALSE</VALUE>                                                                                               
  </PARAM>                                                                                                             
  <PARAM>                                                                                                              
    <NAME>db_valid</NAME>                                                                        
    <VALUE>YES</VALUE>                                                                                   
  </PARAM>                                                                                                             
  <PARAM>                                                                                                              
    <NAME>enable_auditing</NAME>                                                                                    
    <VALUE>FALSE</VALUE>                                                                                               
  </PARAM>                                                                                                             
  <PARAM>                                                                                                              
    <NAME>managament_access</NAME>                                                                        
    <VALUE>TRUE</VALUE>                                                                                   
  </PARAM>                                                                                                             
</PARAMS>
```

Comment: It is preferred that you include what you have tried since it appears you have actually tried something. This give us an idea of what you are trying to accomplish as supposed to just seeing a code writing request. We can show you where you might have gone wrong as well as showing other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative method to Hackerman's answer, you could use a regex positive lookahead e.g. `(?=exampleregex)`.

```
(Get-Content C:\examplepath.xml -raw) -split '(?=<\?xml\ version="1\.0"\ standalone="yes"\?>)' | 
    Where-Object {$_ -ne ""} |
    ForEach-Object {$i=0} {$_ | Out-File "C:\exampleoutput$i.xml"; i++}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's going to output a file for the header line, and then for the body of that, for each XML chunk. Try this RegEx instead `'(?s)(\<\?xml version="1.0".*?)(?=\<\?xml version="1.0")'`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I believe these are functionally equivalent except that your regex will have an empty string in between each element except for the last match. (Which would be filtered out by `$_ -ne ""` anyways) This would be different and yours superior, if `-match` was being used, as there isn't anything being captured in mine.

Comment: You're right, I totally mistook your regex, and missed that it's a look ahead.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
$myXml = @'
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>                                                                                 
    <INSTANCES>                                                                                                            
      <INSTANCE>                                                                                                           
        <HOST_NAME>sstest</HOST_NAME>                                                                               
        <INSTANCE_NAME>SSTEST1</INSTANCE_NAME>                                                                              
        <DATABASE_NAME>SSTEST</DATABASE_NAME>                                                                               
        <OPEN_MODE>READ WRITE</OPEN_MODE>                                                                                                                                                              
        <DBID>192837465</DBID>                                                                                            
      </INSTANCE>                                                                                                          
    </INSTANCES>                                                                                                           
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>                                                                                 
    <PARAMS>                                                                                                               
      <PARAM>                                                                                                              
        <NAME>enable_logging</NAME>                                                                                    
        <VALUE>FALSE</VALUE>                                                                                               
      </PARAM>                                                                                                             
      <PARAM>                                                                                                              
        <NAME>db_valid</NAME>                                                                        
        <VALUE>YES</VALUE>                                                                                   
      </PARAM>                                                                                                             
      <PARAM>                                                                                                              
        <NAME>enable_auditing</NAME>                                                                                    
        <VALUE>FALSE</VALUE>                                                                                               
      </PARAM>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    </PARAMS>
'@

    $separator = [string[]]@('<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>')
    $myXml.Split($separator, [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```